# How do i convert column values in a table to row values using hive

Tags: sql, hive, pivot, explode, unpivot

eg:
current table

```
employee_id employee_name   location_1  location_2  location_3
111 Reeta   Delhi
112 Pinky   Chennai Kerala  Null
113 Tinku   Noida   Ranchi  Jaipur
114 Teena   Null
115 Bing    Assam   Assam
```

Desired table :

```
employee_id employee_name   Location
111 Delhi
112 Pinky   Chennai
112 Pinky   Kerala
113 Tinku   Noida
113 Tinku   Ranchi
113 Tinku   Jaipur
115 Bing    Assam
```

1.The Null values on location column should be ignored while transforming column to row in target table
2. the employee_id and name with null value as location shouldnt be brought to target table.
3.When emplyee_id and employee_name as duplicate values only one should be brought to target table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option uses `union all`:

```
select employee_id, employee_name, location_1 location from mytable where location_1 is not null
union all 
select employee_id, employee_name, location_2 from mytable where location_2 is not null
union all 
select employee_id, employee_name, location_3 from mytable where location_3 is not null
```

A hive-specific approach using a map and `lateral view explode` might be more efficient:

```
select employee_id, employee_name, location
from (
    select 
        employee_id, 
        employee_name, 
        map("location_1", location_1, "location_2", location_2, "location_3", location_3) as mp
    from mytable
) t
lateral view explode(mp) m as locname, location  
where location is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is a `union all`.  But that requires scanning the table multiple times.  So, instead:

```
select tn.*
from (select t.employee_id, t.employee_name,
             (case when n.n = 1 then location_1
                   when n.n = 2 then location_2
                   when n.n = 3 then location_3
              end) as location 
      from t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     ) tn
where location is not null;
```